# Setting Bean's properties with a loop

Tags: java, performance, for-loop, reflection, javabeans

I have a class called Bean which has 3 fields

```
public class Bean {

private Object field0;
private Object field1;
private Object field2;

public Object getField0() {
    return field0;
}

public void setField0(Object field0) {
    this.field0 = field0;
}

public Object getField1() {
    return field1;
}

public void setField1(Object field1) {
    this.field1 = field1;
}

public Object getField2() {
    return field2;
}

public void setField2(Object field2) {
    this.field2 = field2;
}
```

I want to set each one of the fields with data to do so

```
    int j, i;

    for (j = 0; j < body.size(); j++) {
        line = new Bean();
        List row = body.get(j);

        HashMap map = new HashMap(headers.length);

        for (i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {

            line.choosefield2(i, headers, row);
        }
        list.add(line);
    }
```

and choosefield2 is in the bean:

```
public void choosefield2(int i, String[] headers, List row) {

    switch (i) {

    case 0:
        this.setField0(row.get(0));
        break;

    case 1:
        this.setField1(row.get(1));
        break;

    case 2:
        this.setField2(row.get(2));
        break;
```

Can I do this in a for cycle instead of doing a case switch? I have way more than 3 fields so it's not really practical. I heard reflections might be an option. I wanted something like

```
for (i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
        line.setField[i]=row.get(i);
        }
        list.add(line);
    }
```

is this possible? Using JDK 1.6

Comment: Why don´t you use an `ArrayList<Object>`  instead of multiple single Elements?

Comment: because this is to be exported as a datasource for JasperReports thus the need for the Bean

Answer (score 2):

You can, the question is, if you should. Of course you can dynamically search the methods and invoke them via reflection.

```
Class<?> clz = Bean.class;
Method[] methods = clz.getDeclaredMethods();
// etc.
methods[i].invoke( ... );
```

But this does NOT help you make your code more readable typically - and it will slow down your application. Also you of course lose much type-safety and compiler checking, potentially replacing many compiler errors with exceptions occuring during runtime. You should only do so if you have not other choices.

Comment: I thought about it but it needs to be a Bean because this is to be exported to JasperSoft Studio and it requires a JavaBean datasource, in which each Bean element sets a field in the jrxml template

Comment: Feel free to use reflection, it will work, no problem there, but I would only do so in extremly generic code.

Comment: so the switch case is more performance friendly than reflections?

Comment: Note that Javadoc says about getDeclaredMethods() "...The elements in the array returned are not sorted and are not in any particular order". Might be a good idea to sort them somehow before picking by index.

Comment: Doesn't get much faster than short if/switch statements, yes. Reflection has much overhead (comparatively).

Comment: While it is true that reflection is slower than the switch you probably don't have to consider that here - the performance of setters are hardly what slows your application down. What you should focus on foremost is readability - i.e. which solution is easier to understand.

Answer (score 2):

Apache [commons-beanutils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/) is a project that was created to make dealing with beans easier than using raw reflection. You could do something like this:

```
Map<String, String> properties = BeanUtils.describe(bean);
List<String> orderedProperties = new ArrayList<>(properties.keySet()); // cache in an instance variable

// sometime later...
BeanUtils.setProperty(obj, orderedProperties.get(i), value);
```

Just be careful about BeanUtils because I seem to remember it thinking getClass() was a property because it looks like a getter. You might want to check for a setter on each property that BeanUtils finds.

Comment: Should have known that four years ago before I wrote half of that myself ;-)

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like an ideal task for Java 8:

```
// keep and reuse this list:
List<BiConsumer<Bean,Object>> setters=Arrays.asList(
  Bean::setField0, Bean::setField1, Bean::setField2);

Bean bean;
List<Object> values;

assert setters.size()==values.size();
for(int i=0, num=setters.size(); i<num; i++)
    setters.get(i).accept(bean, values.get(i));
```

This code does not use Reflection but rather an explicit list of defined properties, so you’ll notice errors at compile time already. But adding a new property is still as easy as adding `Bean::setNewProperty` to the list at the beginning…

The construction of all beans may look like:

```
List<List<?>> body;

List<Bean> beans=body.stream().map(row-> {
    Bean bean=new Bean();
    for(int i=0, num=setters.size(); i<num; i++)
        setters.get(i).accept(bean, row.get(i));
    return bean;
}).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: The downside to not using reflection is now you have to remember to add a setter to that list every time you add a new property. Not good. Or you write a unit test that fails if all setters aren't present for all properties--but then you would have to use reflection in such a test

Comment: @Samuel: using Reflection in a test case is much better than in production code. Besides that, the Reflection code is not magic. Just making a mistake in the name of a method may cause it to silently consider a method not to be a property.

Comment: If you update your bean, the requirements have obviously changed. And if that's the case, the test case should be updated anyway - preferably first.

Comment: @Holger just like any other kind of code reflection isn't magic. It needs to be written correctly just like any other code, and it needs to be tested just like any code. I don't think that's a reason to not use it in production, especially when it avoids having to update some class whenever you add a method. Plus you're coupling yourself to one specific bean--that really limits the usefulness of the object. Granted OP may not care to reuse it anyway.

Comment: @Samuel: Someone *has* to ensure that the list of values which comes in matches the properties that will be set. Automatically finding a new property via Reflection does not solve that. Besides that, as you said yourself, you have to clean the result of the automatic discovery by at least removing read-only properties like `getClass()`.